# Angularjs promise with jquery ajax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

The factory sends data to the server and its processed correctly but after that the ".then" in the controller is not being called below.

Kindly let me know why the "then" part is not being executed in the controller here after the successful ajax call.

factory

```
myapp.factory('startCampFactory',function($http,$q,$rootScope){

        return {

            startNewCampaign : function(){

            var e = $("input#email");
            var email = e.val();
            var campname = $("input#campaignname").val();
            var about = $("textarea#about").val();
            var tamt = $("input#targetamount").val();
            var edate = $("input#enddate").val();
            var invitees = $("input#invitees").val();
            var file_data = $("#file").prop("files")[0];
            var form_data = new FormData();     
            form_data.append("file",file_data);
            form_data.append("email",email);
            form_data.append("campaignname",campname);
            form_data.append("about",about);
            form_data.append("targetamount",tamt);
            form_data.append("enddate",edate);
            form_data.append("invitees",invitees);
            console.log(email+about+campname);
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: "http://localhost:8080/startcampaign",
                data:form_data,
                contentType:false,
                processData:false,
                cache:false,
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(msg,status)
                {
                    //if(status=="success")

                        deferred.resolve("success");
                        $rootScope.$apply();
                },
                        error:function()
                        {

                            deferred.reject();
                            $rootScope.$apply();
                        }
                });
                return deferred.promise;
                }
        }       
    });
```

conrtoller

```
function startCampCtrl($scope,startCampFactory)
{
    $scope.startcamp = function(){
        $("#submit").prop('disabled',true);

        startCampFactory.startNewCampaign().then(function(d){
            alert("here");
            var temp = "<div class=\"alert alert-dismissable alert-success\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button> <strong>Campaign Saved successfully</strong></div>";
                $(temp).prependTo("#startcamp");
                $("#submit").prop('disabled',false);
                $("input#campaignname").val('');
                $("textarea#about").val('');
                $("input#targetamount").val('');
                $("input#enddate").val('');
                $("input#invitees").val('');
                $("input#file").val('');
        },
        function(){//On error
            var temp = "<div class=\"alert alert-dismissable alert-warning\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button> <strong>Campaign could not be saved, please try again</strong></div>";
                $(temp).prependTo("#startcamp");
                    $("#submit").prop('disabled',false);
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't do that !!! If you're using $.ajax Jquery and dom manipulation through JQuery in a factory, well Angular is nothing and you don't need it ! Put your DOM manipulation into directives and make the ajax request with the AngularJS API's : $http, $resource

Comment: you are defeating the purpose of angular like this

Comment: Actually this wasnt working hence it tried that

$http({method:'POST',url:'/startcampaign',data:form_data,headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
    
    deferred.resolve();
    
   })
   .error(function(){deferred.reject();});
   return deferred.promise;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `$.ajax()` to trigger the call. The correct way to do it is to use the $http service. When a call is made through that service an $apply is automatically trigerred , and all your promises will get executed in that $apply cycle.

If you want to trigger the promises from your success function inside the `$.ajax()` call, 
I suppose you can do it inside an $apply cycle:

```
.....
success:function(msg,status){
                   $rootScope.$apply( function() { 
                        deferred.resolve("success"); 
                     });
}
....
```

Here is the working [fiddle with correct way to invoke promise](http://jsfiddle.net/Vxuke/1/)

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I want to convert from jquery to $http of angular but this below code doesnt send any data to the server

$http({method:'POST',url:'/startcampaign',data:form_data,headers:{'Content-Type'‌​:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
.success(function(data,status,headers,conf‌​ig)
{ 
$rootScope.$apply( function() { 
deferred.resolve(); });
}) 
.error(function(){
$rootScope.$apply( function() { 
deferred.reject();});
}); 
return deferred.promise;

Comment: me too i am binded to using $.ajax,that's because of CORS on the server for POST. may be in prod $http is feisible...